# ms access - generate custom id field

Tags: ms-access, auto-generate

I would like to create an alphanumeric id field which takes for example the first two letters of the name of a project and then starts from 10000...

So in practice if I enter a name in a form called "institute" the id field should look like 
"IN10001" and should increment when i select another name starting with"in.." ->"IN10002 (it should look for the highest value under "IN"

This should be possible for all combination of two letters AA , AB, .... ZA... ZZ

I hope you have understood my question.
I did some research on this but couldn't find something concrete.

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,
PK

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea to me, as you're storing meaningful data as a subpart of a field. It also looks like duplicate data. The days of users having to remember customer codes and the like should be long gone -- you give them a dropdown list or an easy find functionality that uses the radical idea of allowing them to search on THE ACTUAL CUSTOMER NAME. Anything else is very 1979.

Answer (score 1):

Have a parameter called:  [ProjectAbbrev] and set it to the 2-Letter Abbreviation value.

This query looks in your Project table (You'll need to know that)

```
select @ProjectAbbrev & CStr(max(CInt(Right([ProjectID], Len([ProjectID]) -2))) + 1)
from Projects
Where Left([ProjectID],2) = [ProjectAbbrev];
```